# Enforcing Restritions On DataContracts

Tags: .net, xsd, datacontract, restriction

Is there any way one can enforce restrictions on values passed in the form of data contracts as parameters to a given WCF Service?

For instance, please consider the contrived and certainly *non-compilable* example of this `Vehicle` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Vehicle
{
    [DataMember]
    [Restriction(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 30)] // Certainly not allowed... or is it?
    public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
}
```

Since, of course, nobody expects to find a vehicle with more than, say, 30 wheels, I would like to limit the range of the `NumberOfWheels` to a value between 1 and 30. Is there any way one can use XSD restrictions/facets to limit the range of acceptable values in this case?

(Please note that I could, of course, change the type of the `NumberOfWheels` from `int` to, say, `byte` to further limit the range of possible values. However, that wouldn't solve the problem... Of course, no one expects a vehicle to have 255 wheels.)

Comment: Aside from putting what appears to be domain validation in the service layer, can you use the dataannotation validators? i.e. [Range(1, 30)]. They are located in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations library.

Comment: As an addendum it should be noted that only the type definition will be sent to the client, so while we can do validation after the data is recieved from the client, we cannot force behavior on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using dataannotations:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    [Range(1, 30)]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public void DoWork(Test t)
{            
    // this will throw validation exceptions, overloads are available to trap and handle
    Validator.ValidateObject(t, new ValidationContext(t), true);
    //do stuff here
}
```

Again it should be noted that behavior cannot be sent/forced to the client using this method. It will only validate that the object fulfills as described validation.